# 投票に関する翻訳の表記揺れにどのように対応しますか？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

現在のヘルプセンターとFAQでは、Upvote/Downvoteに関する和訳として「賛成/反対」と「プラス/マイナス」が使われています。具体例を挙げるとヘルプセンターの[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)ページにおいて、「反対」と「マイナス」が以下に引用したように混在して使われています。

個人的にはこのような表記揺れは、読みやすさを損ないやすく好ましくないと思うので、何か 1 つの表現に統一する必要があると考えていますが、この表記揺れにどのように対応するべきでしょうか？

> ### マイナス投票とは?
>
> マイナス投票とは、「マイナス票の投票」とも呼ばれ、どの質問および回答が最も役に立たないかをコミュニティが示す方法です。
>
> ### どんな時にマイナス投票したらいいですか?
>
> はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿、または明らかに、そして危険なほど不正確な回答を見つけたら、マイナス票を使用してください。
>
> 1 日に投票できる数には制限があり、その上回答への反対票は信用度を若干消費するので、よく考えて使ってください。
>
> ### 反対投票の方法は?
>
> 各投稿の左の大きな下向き矢印をクリックします。
>
> 同じボタンをクリックすると投票を取り消すことができますが、短い時間の間だけなので、クリックは慎重に行ってください。マイナス票をプラス票に変更するには上向き矢印をクリックします。逆の場合も同じです。

Comment: 2021年6月現在の投票状況から、「プラス投票」「マイナス投票」に統一で一旦反映させていただければと思います。今後も引き続きみなさんのご意見をぜひお伺いしたいです m_ _m。

Answer (score 6):

実際この揺れは翻訳する度に毎回悩みます。日本語としては「賛成投票」「反対投票」の方が自然なのですが、スタック・オーバーフローやスタック・オーバーフロー メタにおける投票は必ずしも「賛成」「反対」を示すものではないので悩ましいところです。

最近の個人的な好みとしては「プラス投票」「マイナス投票」の方が文章中での使い勝手が良いように思っています。ただあんまり理由が無くて自信が無いので、他の方のご意見も伺いたいです。

Answer (score 2):

翻訳を行う際、複数の表現で言い換えができる場合には (無理の出ない範囲で) より文字幅の短い方を選択するのも一つの方法だと思っています。

しかし今回の場合は「反対票」という表現がしっくりこないので、「プラス/マイナス」に揃える案を私も推します。

Answer (score 1):

直訳すると「上げ投票」「下げ投票」で、実際に回答の表示順位を「上げる／下げる」という具体的機能を表した原語のネーミングではないかと思います。三角と逆三角のボタンとも関連しているので、私は個人的に「上げ・下げ」は入っていた方がいいかな。意訳して日本語の語彙体系に従来からある用語から選ぶと、賛成・反対とかプラス・マイナスにはなるかと思いますが、具体性が薄れてやや観念的になるというか。
多分、本家でも単純に accept/reject とか、up/down と言わずに、up-vode/down-vote と組み合わせているのはスタックオーバーフロー（固有かどうかはわかりませんが）的な一種の造語ですよね？

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、ヘルプセンターの「ヘルプページを検索する...」で調べると以下のように見つかります。どちらに統一するにしてもそれなりの作業になるでしょう。
私自身はプラス／マイナスが良いと考えています。

---

**投票に関してプラス／マイナスで表記されているページ**

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)
[私たちのモデル - スパム発信者にならないようにどうすればいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)
[信用度とモデレーション - 信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
[信用度とモデレーション - 通報が却下された時はどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags)
[権限 - マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
[権限 - プラス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
[レビューキュー - 低品質な投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality)
[レビューキュー - 遅延回答キューを使用するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers)
[レビューキュー - 初めての投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts)

---

**投票に関して賛成／反対で表記されているページ**

[質問にあたって - 自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
[質問にあたって - 私のアカウントからの質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)
[質問にあたって - 一部の質問が削除される理由とその方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)
[回答にあたって - 良い回答を書くには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
[回答にあたって - 他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)
[回答にあたって - 私のアカウントからの回答が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)
[私たちのモデル - 気持ちよく参加するために](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)
[私たちのモデル - バッジとは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)
[信用度とモデレーション - 信用度ページで、「連続投票が取り消されました」 で信用度が変更されているのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)
[信用度とモデレーション - 投票が重要なのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
[信用度とモデレーション - 信用度ページで、「ユーザーは削除されました」で信用度が変更されているのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)
[権限 - 確立したユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)
[権限 - どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)
[権限 - タグの別名の作成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)
[権限 - レビュー キューへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)
[権限 - 懸賞の設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)
[権限 - 新規ユーザーの制限の解除](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)
[権限 - 投稿の作成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)

Comment: 2021/08/04 に「賛成／反対」->「プラス／マイナス」への変更が完了し、ヘルプページでの「賛成／反対」での表記がゼロになりました 。

Comment: お疲れさまでした。

Answer (score 1):

「賛成票」表記の残存：

各人の信用度履歴の表示で「賛成票を取り消す」というのが残存していました。
投票の方は「プラス投票」に修正されています。

なのでもしかしたら「反対票を取り消す」というのも残存しているかもしれません。

見付けたのは此処のページ
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/52671/riku?tab=reputation

該当部分のイメージはこれ：
[image: 信用度賛成票を取り消す]

Comment: [こちら](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3276)を「プラス票を取り消す」に変更し、先ほどサイトに反映されました。「反対票」で検索をかけたところ今のところ見当たりませんでしたので、また何か気づかれましたらメタでシェアお願いいたします。